# GDT Core Selection for an MF Switching Action

Tags: mosfet, inverter, gate-driving, ferrite

I am designing an MF (approx. 1.5 MHz) MOSFET driver for an inverter circuit. I’d searched numerous driving strategies (according to the circuit’s needs like high frequency operation, drive-input voltage limitations on a MOSFET as a switch, etc.) and consequently, I’ve arrived at the driving style that utilises GDT.

The problem that I’ve faced is that for the application, the right ferrite core (It is going to be a ring core as I am going to decide the voltage conversion ratio.) selection, for me, is quite demanding.

Considering my application, what should I look at when choosing the suitable core material? And, if it is possible, could you give an example ferrite material for the switching frequency of concern?

Comment: A medium frequency 1.5 MHz gate driver transformer core material must have reasonable loss at 1.5 MHz, and good permeability. Now hit the data sheets.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks for your attention and advice, I've been reading for datasheets for a while and it is a really time-consuming thing to do, but this is how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: You could try using this core: B64290L0044X038 the permeability is very high and ive tested it at 1Mhz driving a single mosfet.The fet was driving an inductive load at 30v 2a it worked fine for me

Comment: @Mr.Infinite Okay, I'll look at it. Thank you for the support.